# Angular Material badges Implementation

Tags: angular-material-6

How can I implement the badges eg: +2 (which returns an array length ) using angular material. By clicking +2 displays the remaining array item.

I have attached the image of my problem below. Looking for a positive answer.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv8PT.png)

Comment: where is the image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv8PT.png

Comment: Can i know how can i Implement tht count using angular material

Comment: does it have to be a badge,  i mean considering what's there in the image, it could be just a `<span>` or `<p>` with `{{data}}` inside it and some `css` to change the color.

Comment: May you're looking for something like [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eketad?file=app%2Fbadge-overview-example.html)